# xml to dict changing tag name in python

Tags: python, dictionary, xmltodict

I am trying to convert an xml data to python dictionary data.
xmltodict is working fine with my code.

below is the sample:

```
  myxml = """
 <mydocument has="an attribute">
   <and>
     <many>elements</many>
     <many>more elements</many>
   </and>
   <plus a="complex">
     element as well
   </plus>
 </mydocument>
 """
```

if I write **data = xmltodict.parse(myxml)** then it works fine. but my xml is much more larger than this and I want to rename all the tag-name with ***plus*** to ***children***.
and then the output dictionary will contain children key instead of plus key.
any suggestions pleas...

Comment: Why wouldn't you try to replace `plus` (using pattern matching to match `<plus ` and `</plus>`) throughout the file and then try parsing the xml?

Answer (score 0):

You could rename the `<plus></plus>` tag first using a library like `ElementTree` and then convert to dict. Here's the code:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
import xmltodict
import json

myxml = """
 <mydocument has="an attribute">
   <and>
     <many>elements</many>
     <many>more elements</many>
   </and>
   <plus a="complex">
     element as well
   </plus>
 </mydocument>
 """
#rename tag
root = ET.fromstring(myxml)
for elem in root.iter('plus'):
    elem.tag = 'children'

newxml = ET.tostring(root, encoding='utf8', method='xml')
xml_dict = dict(xmltodict.parse(newxml)) #convert to Ordered dict and then a normal dict(optional, OrderedDict is returned by default if only using xmltodict)
print(json.dumps(xml_dict, indent=4)) #pretty print to view dict tree(optional)
#Output:
 {
    "mydocument": {
        "@has": "an attribute",
        "and": {
            "many": [
                "elements",
                "more elements"
            ]
        },
        "children": {
            "@a": "complex",
            "#text": "element as well"
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As I commented above, I would suggest to string replace `plus` to `children` using pattern matching.

```
import re

myxml = """
 <mydocument has="an attribute">
   <and>
     <many>elements</many>
     <many>more elements</many>
   </and>
   <plus a="complex">
     element as well
   </plus>
 </mydocument>
 """

myxml = re.sub('(?<=</)?plus', 'children', myxml)
print(myxml)
```

which results to

> ```
>  <mydocument has="an attribute">
>    <and>
>      <many>elements</many>
>      <many>more elements</many>
>    </and>
>    <children a="complex">
>      element as well
>    </children>
>  </mydocument>
> ```